# Is there a shortcut to add an activity to the manifest in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a feature in Eclipse to do this?

Comment: No AFAIK. And why would you need one though?

Comment: It's not like you do it 10 times an hour :p Don't be lazy.

Comment: Actually, I think it might be a useful feature particularly for people new to Android development. How many questions here have you seen when the problem is the asker has forgotten to add their activity to the manifest? I know I've seen quite a number.

Comment: Currently there are no plugins/automatic way to add your activity to the Manifest. You have to code it manually or use the XML UI to do it.

Comment: @Squonk - Running the Android Lint tool will generate warnings for any activities not declared in the manifest. It would be nice if you could suppress the warning for library projects (for which declaring activities in the manifest is useless).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by a shortcut, but the Android Manifest Editor (the default editor for manifest files) has some UI help. Click on the Application tab, click the Add button, select Activity, and then you can click the Browse button next to the activity name to browse for available activities to add to your manifest.

Comment: +1 I'd forgotten about that. I almost always just edit the XML directly.